# How to use custom converter org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter with EclipseList?

Tags: eclipselink, converters

I am trying to implement `org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.converters.Converter` use it in my orm.xml. Most examples show me how to do it with annotations. Like use `@TypeConverter` in entity class. But I can't use annotations. How do I am trying to create orm.xml using java  (based on java classes generated based on orm_2_1.xsd using xjc tool). For some reason type-converters are missing in xsd definition.

So my question is how do I use custom converter without using annotations. How to get it to orm.xml?

[This link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_typeconverter.htm#CEGBJCIH) says:

> "...Each TypeConverter must be uniquely named and can be defined at the class, field and property level and can be specified within an Entity, MappedSuperclass and Embeddable class. A TypeConverter is always specified by using an @Convert annotation"

So does it mean we can't mention the convert in orm.xml? Is there any reason it was designed (typeconvert are skipped in orm_2_1.XSD?)

Answer (score 1):

this is described at [eclipselink docs](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_converter.htm#sthash.EuXgG2t4.dpuf):

in the eclipselink-orm.xml

```
<entity class="Employee"> 
... 
  <attributes> 
  ...
    <basic name="gender">
      <convert>genderConverter</convert>
      <converter name="genderConverter" class="org.myorg.converters.GenderConverter"/>
    </basic> 
  ... 
  </attributes> 
</entity>
```